# Self-hosting ServiceStack REST Service on local network

Tags: c#, servicestack

I was wondering if anyone could help - I have a local network (wireless, my computer and a laptop connected to it) and I've tried hosting a rest service developed with ServiceStack on it. If I run the application on the computer (a console app for now) and try to access the service using the machine IP or 127.0.0.1 it works fine - but if I try and access it from the laptop, using the computer's IP it simply stalls, and the REST service is never called.

I've tried turning off all firewalls etc, running everything in Admin mode but still nothing.. am I missing something simple to get this working?

Any help is much appreciated!

Some of the code samples (My AppHost class is inheriting from the AppHostHttpListenerBase)

```
restServiceToStart.Value.Init ();
restServiceToStart.Value.Start (_HostUri);
```

where for my main machine, the _HostUri is set to `"http://my-ip-address:8080/"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't listed the code you use to start your AppHost (please be descriptive when asking questions) so I'm going to assume you're not listening to `http://*:{port}/`, e.g. from the [Self Hosting wiki](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Self-hosting):

```
var appHost = new AppHost();
appHost.Init();
appHost.Start("http://*:1337/");
```

The `*` wildcard says to listen on every local network interface.

Comment: Hmm I tried that, as well as pinging the machines and they both get responses from each other, they just can't call the service hosted on the other machine for some reason :S

Comment: Then it has to be a firewall. Could be on the local machines, try turning them off first so you can find out which one it is, then once you identify the culprit add a more fine-grained rule allowing it through.

Comment: Yep you were right it was the firewall - for some reason I had them both turned off earlier and tried it but still nothing, after I restarted both machines but it works fine :)