# ServiceStack JsonServiceClient based test fails, but service works in browser

Tags: web-services, nunit, servicestack

After I got my single-page web app working *(web pages served with ServiceStack's RazorFormat() MVC, not .ASP MVC)*, I ran a *(previously passing)* test for the service.  The test failed.  Tested the web app again *(debug run, navigate to `//localhost:1337/ResourceList` in the browser)*: still working.  Is something wrong with my test?

**Here's the error:**

```cs
Test Name:  TestResourceList
Test FullName:  [0-1015]ServiceWrapper.Test.TestSWrapperServices.TestResourceList
Test Source:    c:\Users\uname\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ServiceWrapper\UnitTestProject1\ServiceTests.cs : line 96
Test Outcome:   Failed
Test Duration:  0:00:02.188

Result Message: 
System.Net.WebException : Unable to connect to the remote server
  ----> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException : No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:1337
Result StackTrace:  
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
at ServiceStack.ServiceClient.Web.ServiceClientBase.Send[TResponse](String httpMethod, String relativeOrAbsoluteUrl, Object request)
at ServiceStack.ServiceClient.Web.ServiceClientBase.Get[TResponse](IReturn`1 request)
at ServiceWrapper.Test.TestSWrapperServices.TestResourceList() in c:\Users\uname\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ServiceWrapper\UnitTestProject1\ServiceTests.cs:line 98
--SocketException
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)
```

**Here's the test:**

```cs
namespace ServiceWrapper.Test
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class TestSWrapperServices
    {
        AppHost appHost;
        private const string ListeningOn = "http://*:1337/";
        public const string Host = "http://localhost:1337";
        private const string BaseUri = Host + "/";

        [TestFixtureSetUp]
        public void OnTestFixtureSetUp()
        {
            var appSettings = new AppSettings();
            var username = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERNAME");
            var userdomain = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERDOMAIN");

            AppHost.AppConfig = new AppConfig(new AppSettings());

            appHost = new AppHost();

            // initialize Service Server
            ServiceServer.SetUser(AppHost.AppConfig.UserName, AppHost.AppConfig.Password);
            ServiceServer.SetLog(String.Empty);

            try
            {
                appHost.Init();
                appHost.Start(ListeningOn);
            }
            catch (HttpListenerException ex)
            {
                if (ex.ErrorCode == 5)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("You need to run the following command (as admin):");
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("  netsh http add urlacl url={0} user={1}\\{2} listen=yes",
                        ListeningOn, userdomain, username);
                }
                else
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("ERROR: {0}: {1}", ex.GetType().Name, ex.Message);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("ERROR: {0}: {1}", ex.GetType().Name, ex.Message);
            }
        }

        [TestFixtureTearDown]
        public void OnTestFixtureTearDown()
        {
            appHost.Dispose();
        }

        [Test]
        public void TestResourceList()
        {
            JsonServiceClient client = new JsonServiceClient(BaseUri);
            ResourceList response = client.Get(new ResourceList());
            Assert.Contains("Some Value", response.property);
        }
        [Test]
    }
}
```

Comment: Could be a firewall or network issue similar to this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15888834/self-hosting-servicestack-rest-service-on-local-network). Maybe try changing ListeningOn to http://localhost:1337.

Comment: I'll give it a try.  I'm skeptical, as the test was working before I added the RazorFormat() to the config -- so the problem shouldn't be related to a firewall -- I didn't change the ListeningOn since I first setup servicestack on this project.

Comment: And - makes no difference if I have `localhost` or `*` in my ListeningOn value.  It's exactly the same error in test.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I upgraded to the latest ServiceStack - 3.9.55, and it still didn't work.  So, I started over again, sanity checking from the beginning.  It turns out that the program.cs ListeningOn has `http://*:1337/` while the nunit TestFixture ListeningOn was `http://localhost:1337/`

Checking urlacl (as admin) for `http://localhost:1337/`:

```
    C:\Windows\system32>netsh http show urlacl url=http://localhost:1337/

    URL Reservations:
    -----------------
```

Checking urlacl (as admin) for `http://*:1337/`:

```
    C:\Windows\system32>netsh http show urlacl url=http://*:1337/

    URL Reservations:
    -----------------

        Reserved URL            : http://*:1337/
            User: DOMAIN\user
                Listen: Yes
                Delegate: No
                SDDL: D:(A;;GX;;;S-1-5-21-2595267603-2801715271-1705165942-1002)
```

My earlier troubleshooting left the two projects with inconsistent ListeningOn values.  Interestingly, using http://*:1337/ doesn't work as a wildcard url, as perhaps I had expected.

Here's a handy code snippet to help you build the add urlacl command.  It also provides a useful (!) sanity check on the exact url you're listening on.

```
    Console.WriteLine("You need to run the following command:");
    Console.WriteLine("  netsh http add urlacl url={0} user={1}\\{2} listen=yes",
    ListeningOn, userdomain, username);
```

**--- Update ---**

Upgrading ServiceStack eliminated the 'connection actively refused' error message.  Once `ListeningOn` values were unified, the real
error message was exposed:

```
Result Message: ServiceStack.ServiceClient.Web.WebServiceException : Service Unavailable
Result StackTrace:  
at ServiceStack.ServiceClient.Web.ServiceClientBase.ThrowWebServiceException[TResponse](Exception ex, String requestUri)
at ServiceStack.ServiceClient.Web.ServiceClientBase.ThrowResponseTypeException[TResponse](Object request, Exception ex, String requestUri)
at ServiceStack.ServiceClient.Web.ServiceClientBase.HandleResponseException[TResponse](Exception ex, Object request, String requestUri, Func`1 createWebRequest, Func`2 getResponse, TResponse& response)
at ServiceStack.ServiceClient.Web.ServiceClientBase.Send[TResponse](String httpMethod, String relativeOrAbsoluteUrl, Object request)
at ServiceStack.ServiceClient.Web.ServiceClientBase.Get[TResponse](IReturn`1 request)
at RemoteServerWrapper.Test.TestRSWrapperServices.TestDataList() in c:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\RemoteServerWrapper\UnitTestProject1\ServiceTests.cs:line 183
```

It's still obscure -- but at least it's not reporting something that's completely different from the real issue.  So then I implemented trace in my app.config, like this:

```
<configuration>

  <!-- ... other config settings ... -->

  <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.Net" tracemode="includehex" maxdatasize="1024">
        <listeners>
          <add name="System.Net"/>
          <add name="console"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="System.Net.HttpListener">
        <listeners>
          <add name="System.Net"/>
          <add name="console"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
    <switches>
      <add name="System.Net" value="Verbose"/>
      <add name="System.Net.HttpListener" value="Verbose"/>
    </switches>
     <sharedListeners>
      <add name="console" 
        type="System.Diagnostics.ConsoleTraceListener" 
        initializeData="false"/>
      <add name="System.Net"
        type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener"
        initializeData="network.log"
      />
    </sharedListeners>
    <trace autoflush="true"/>
  </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

Which exposed a better error message:

```
ERROR: [::1]:1337 Request not found: /datarequest?DataKey=some_key&startDate=20130701&endDate=20130708
```

OK - now I have to pull in the servicestack sources so I can step through the code and figure out why I'm getting 'Not Found' in the test, when it works when I 'debug/run' and test via the browser.  Turns out that `RestHandler.FindMatchingRestPath(httpMethod, pathInfo, contentType)` wasn't returning a match.  Humm.  Why is that?  The AppHost is declared identically.  So, what's different?

The rest services live in my project's main assembly.  When run from 'debug/run' the default assembly has the services, and everything works.  But when run from the test project, with the services assembly added as a reference, servicestack can't find them.  They're not in the default location, relative to the test project.  So I added an AppHost class at the top of my test file, rather than relying on the one from my program.cs, and declared it as follows:

```
public class RSWrapperServicesAppHostHttpListener
            : AppHostHttpListenerBase
{
    public RSWrapperServicesAppHostHttpListener()
        : base("RSWrapper Services Tests", typeof(DataRequestService).Assembly) { } 

// 'DataRequestService' is a random rest service class, 
// defined in the referenced services assembly

}
```

Now ServiceStack is happy, and my tests work again.

How did they ever work?  Originally everything was jumbled together all in one project.  Once I separated things into separate assemblies, i.e. DTO, Services, Business Logic and Tests, I broke it.  But since I was temporarily holding off on unit tests while getting the UI working, I didn't notice right away.