# ServiceStack NUnit Test Debugging Connection Refused Issue

Tags: visual-studio-2012, nunit, servicestack

In this question: [ServiceStack JsonServiceClient based test fails, but service works in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16819463/149060) I'm looking for some clue as to why the test generates an exception, when an interactive browser test succeeds.  Originally I could run tests and interact via the browser.

Now I'm asking for some direction on how to debug this.  Basically, if I step through my test case, I reach a line like this: `Tranactions response = client.Get(request);` and then it raises an exception.  I'm thinking I should download the servicestack source and add the project to my solution, in order to step through that code and get further insight into what's going on.  Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to update the project to the latest ServiceStack release to start.  Then, I repeated my earlier troubleshooting steps.  The problem was resolved.  See: [ServiceStack JsonServiceClient based test fails, but service works in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16819463/149060) for further details.